# Getting low accuracy while using Data Generator class and fitting in CNN model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Below is the code for two architectures of the model. Model one uses data generator class to fit the data whereas model 2 uses direct numpy arrays of train and test data to fit the model. With the first model the accuracy is so low whereas with the second one the accuracy is good. Can someone tell me what the issue is with using the data generator class? The data augmentation layer in model 2 includes the layer for resizing the image to shape (160,160,3). Feel free to ask anything that I missed to provide in the question.

```py
    class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
        def __init__(self, images, labels=None, mode='fit', batch_size=64, dim=(160, 160),             channels=3, n_classes=10, shuffle=True, augment=False):
             #initializing the configuration of the generator
        self.images = images
        self.labels = labels
        self.mode = mode
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.dim = dim
        self.channels = channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.augment = augment
        self.on_epoch_end()

        if augment:
          self.augmenter=albu.Compose([
              albu.HorizontalFlip(0.5),
              albu.VerticalFlip(0.5),
              albu.RandomRotate90(0.2),
              albu.ElasticTransform(p=0.2),
              albu.Resize(height=dim[0], width=dim[1])
          ])
        else:
          self.augmenter=albu.Resize(height=dim[0],width=dim[1])

    #method to be called after every epoch
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexes = np.arange(self.images.shape[0])
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    #return numbers of steps in an epoch using samples & batch size basically number of batches
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.images) / self.batch_size))

    #this method is called with the batch number as an argument to #obtain a given batch of data
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        #generate one batch of data
        #generate indexes of batch
        batch_indexes = self.indexes[index * self.batch_size:(index+1) * self.batch_size]

        #generate mini-batch of X
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.channels))
        for i, ID in enumerate(batch_indexes):
            #generate pre-processed image
            img = self.images[ID]
            #image rescaling
            img = img.astype(np.float32)/255.0
            #augmentation on the training dataset
            img = self.augmenter(image=img)['image']
            X[i] = img

        #generate mini-batch of y
        if self.mode == 'fit':
          y = self.labels[batch_indexes]
          return X, y

        elif self.mode == 'predict':
          return X

        else:
          raise AttributeError("The mode should be set to either 'fit' or 'predict'.")

     def model_1():
       base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(160,160,3),
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
      base_model.trainable=False # this is to freese the model
      inputs=tf.keras.Input(shape=((160,160,3)))
      x=preprocess_input(inputs)
      x=base_model(x,training=False)# to keep normal layer non-traninable
      x=layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
      x=layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
      outputs=layers.Dense(units=10,activation='softmax')(x)
      model=Model(inputs,outputs)
      return model
    model_1=model_1()
    history1=model_1.fit(train_data_generator,validation_data=valid_data_generator,epochs=20)

    def model_2():
      base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(160,160,3),
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
      base_model.trainable=False # this is to freese the model
      inputs=tf.keras.Input(shape=((32,32,3)))
      x=data_augmentation(inputs)
      x=preprocess_input(x)
      x=base_model(x,training=False)# to keep normal layer non-traninable
      x=layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
      x=layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
      outputs=layers.Dense(units=10,activation='softmax')(x)
      model=Model(inputs,outputs)
      return model

    model2=model_2()
    history2=model2.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=64,epochs=5,validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

Comment: What is low accuracy? Random guessing? What happens when you train with `shuffle=False`?

Comment: @Anonymous By low accuracy I mean say for 5 epochs model 1 gives accuracy of 11% in first epoch and increases to 20% at 5th epoch which is very low. Wheareas for model 2 the accuracy of model in first epoch is 56% and increases to 65% at 5th epoch which is atleast better. Also keeping shuffle = False is not giving good accuracy.